# Meaning of a star as a visibility specifier in Doxygen class diagrams

Tags: doxygen

Some UML-style class diagrams generated by Doxygen from C++ code have a '*' for the visibility qualifier, and additionally some such members are duplicated, e.g. with foo() and fred() in this mocked-up example:

```
public:    virtual void foo() = 0;
protected: virtual void bar() = 0;
public:    virtual void fred() = 0;
```

the output may be:

```
+ foo()
# bar()
* foo()
* fred()
```

so foo() appears as both public and '*', fred() just as '*'. This doesn't appear to correlate with other language features such as virtual, pure, templated derivations or overloads, or inherited definitions, or return type.

What does the '*' visibility indicate?

[using Doxygen version 1.8.13, the current release at time of writing]

Comment: It might mean "pure virtual public function" or just "virtual public function"

Comment: Apparently not - in the real case behind this mockup there's another pure virtual that doesn't get the duplicate-with-star handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**: it's an artifact of the member grouping mechanism and doesn't appear to convey any language information, i.e. it's not an extension of UML.

**Details**: specifically the '*' is generated from `DotNode::writeBox()` enumerating member groups, [excerpted from here](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blame/9dbdf881dc5f0644777cc5732e7751325b508c91/src/dot.cpp#L649):

```
MemberGroupSDict::Iterator mgdi(*m_classDef->memberGroupSDict);
MemberGroup *mg;
for (mgdi.toFirst();(mg=mgdi.current());++mgdi)
{
  if (mg->members())
  {
    writeBoxMemberList(t,'*',*mg->members(),m_classDef);
  }
}
```

The Doxygen manual description of [member groups](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#memgroup) behaviour notes both automatic grouping ("groups things together on type and protection level") and explicitly via enclosure within `///@{` and `///@}` grouping annotations. Brief experimentation shows that either the grouping annotations or explicitly naming an automatic group via `///@name` results in the members being added as a group and so doubly listed with the '*' visibility. For example this class generates the subsequent diagram:

```
class base {
 public:
  ///@{
  void pubfoo();
  void pubbar();
  ///@}
  void pubfoo(char); // no '*' visibility
 protected:
  ///@name Group2
  void protfoo(); ///< Foolishly
  void protbar(); ///< Barely
};
```

[image: Generated class diagram for 'base']

It's a venerable feature (from 2004), seemingly unconditional (at least brief examination of the code didn't show any control mechanism beyond the big hammer of "UML_LOOK=NO"), and safe to ignore.